How to use abstract class as variable type in C#
I'm trying to use an abstract class as variable type in C# and getting System.StackOverflowException: 'Exception_WasThrown' error when try to read ResultData.ValuesDescription
public abstract class Plugin
{
    public abstract string Name { get; }
    public abstract string Description { get; }
    public abstract Results ResultData { get; }
    public abstract bool Init(string Symbol);
}
public abstract class Results
{
    public abstract bool Values { get; set; }
    public abstract string ValuesDescription { get; set; }
}

public class Test : Plugin
{
    public override string Name { get => "Lortem Ipsum Moving Average"; }
    public override string Description { get => "Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."; }
    public override Results ResultData {
        get {
            ResultData.Values = true;
            ResultData.ValuesDescription = "Lorem Ipsum result in numeric format";
            return ResultData;
        }
    }
    public override bool Init(string Symbol)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

Any suggestion on what's going on?

ResultData.Values = true; – what (do you think) is ResultData in this line? And what do you intend to achieve with that line?

Results is abstract and cannot be effectively used on its own. Do you have a class that extends Results somewhere for your Test class to actually use?

Simply put, you can't instantiate an abstract class. You are trying to work around the fact that you can't instantiate an abstract class and do it anyway, but that's just not possible.

Can you describe what you are trying to do in the get for the ResultData property?  Currently any attempt to read that property will recursively try to read itself indefinitely, resulting in the exception you're seeing.  (Which, incidentally, has nothing to do with abstract classes.  An infinitely recursive property will exhibit this behavior on any class.)  But why are you trying to do that in that property?  What is the goal there?

Name, Description and Results are just to expose plugin predetermined properties. They are readonly.

Outside the problem at hand: Why would you have abstract classes here, in the first place? Plugin seems as if it should be an IPlugin interface.

@DPZ The ResultData getter is returning a Results class instance. That class instance has to be instantiated somewhere.

Sure @Fildor. Was an Interface and now converting to abstract class.

"That class instance has to be instantiated somewhere." ,,, which it cannot, because it itself is abstract and there are no inheritors. "Was an Interface and now converting to abstract class" - why though? It doesn't make sense. You share no implementation.

@DPZ: "Name, Description and Results are just to expose plugin predetermined properties." - Name and Description are properties, Results is a type.  These are very different things.  Do you mean ResultData instead?  It's important to be consistent, and if the names of types/properties/etc. are confusing then they should probably be changed.  "They are readonly." - Yes, and one of them is infinitely reading itself.  Why?  What was the goal for that?

No I don’t have instantiate someware @Abion47

The easiest fix would be to make Results concrete and not abstract, which doesn't make sense anyway. Then you can return an actual instance. If that is always the same one or new ones depends on intended behavior.

@Fildor I was respondig to Abion47 “Do you have a class that extends Results somewhere for your Test class to actually use?”. Sorry for misunderstanding, I’m not Eng native and trying to learn a new not easy concept.

The answer from @ipodtouch0218 covers the immediate issue of the stack overflow error from the ResultData getter calling itself, but the core underlying issue is that you currently have a Result class that is marked as abstract with no concrete implementation. You cannot use an abstract class that doesn't have an implementation somewhere.
From what it sounds like, you want implementations of Plugin to have read-only descriptor metadata associated with them. You can do this with an abstract Results class, but you will need to create subclasses that implement its getters. For instance:
public abstract class Results
{
    // Mark these with only getters because setters don't make
    // sense if they are intended to be read only.
    public abstract bool Values { get; }
    public abstract string ValuesDescription { get; }
}

public class TestResults : Results
{
    // Create a static instance so you don't need to instantiate
    // over and over again.
    public static readonly TestResults instance = new TestResults();

    // Provide a concrete implementation for these properties
    public override bool Values { 
        get { return true;  } 
    }
    public override String ValuesDescription { 
        get { return "Lorem Ipsum result in numeric format"; } 
    }
}

public abstract class Plugin
{
    // ...
    public abstract Results ResultData { get; }
    // ...
}

public class Test : Plugin
{
    // ...
    public override Results ResultData 
    {
        // Return the static instance
        get { return TestResults.instance; }
    }
    // ...
}

As for whether this is a good approach to accomplish this, it's certainly a bloated solution. For one thing, it would make more sense to implement this with interfaces rather than abstract classes, or alternatively using some kind of factory pattern. And for another, seeing as the Results class is meant to only contain static information that will never change, it begs the question as to why it needs to be its own class at all and why its properties can't simply be part of the Plugin/Test classes, or at the very least converted into a simple struct or record.

Thanks also to @ipodtouch0218. Both responses help me to better understand where and why I’m wrong.

Properties are (effectively) shorthand for a getter/setter method pair (oversimplification!). If you replace your ResultData property with a method, you'll quickly see why you're getting a StackOverflowException, and it has nothing to do with the abstract class:
public override Results GetResultData() {
    GetResultData().Values = true;
    GetResultData().ValuesDescription = "Lorem Ipsum result in numeric format";
    return GetResultData();
}

Your code is trying to access ResultData from within the ResultData getter. So that runs the ResultData getter, which runs it again, and again... infinitely.
To fix this, you actually have to store a Results variable somewhere. This is known as a "backing field"¹:
 // Be sure to assign this
private Results _resultsData;

public override Results ResultData {
    get {
        _resultsData.Values = true;
        _resultsData.ValuesDescription = "Lorem Ipsum result in numeric format";
        return _resultsData;
    }
}

Alternatively, you could make a new class that inherits from Results each time. Depends on if you need unique instances or not:
public override Results ResultData {
    get {
        // Has to be a child class, because Results is abstract
        ResultsImpl newResult = new ResultsImpl();
        newResult.Values = true;
        newResult.ValuesDescription = "Lorem Ipsum result in numeric format";
        return newResult;
    }
}


¹: While Microsoft Learn states that backing fields are "A private field that stores the data exposed by a public property", this sort of usage (like a shared cached instance of an object that you modify in the getter) makes it arguably not a true backing field. I just don't have a better name for it.

Why would you modify a backing field in a getter?

@knittl in their case, it's more of just a shared instance of a class than a true backing field. I just called it one since the docs describe them as "A private field that stores the data exposed by a public property". Modification usually is unexpected, but isn't restricted by the compiler either, getters don't have to be readonly.

This code would throw an error on new Results() because Results is abstract. The stack overflow issue is covering up the other issue that there isn't any class in OP's given code that extends Results giving a concrete implementation to instantiate and utilize.

Making Results concrete would make more sense anyway. There is nothing about it that needs to be abstract. It looks like a DTO. In fact, I'd make it a record.

If you want a proper term for this "backing field", I vote for "extremely memory inefficient pseudo-readonly singleton".

@Abion47 ah good catch, I've edited my answer to not do new Results.
